# Old Atom d945gclf2 with 10TB no boot device found

Tags: grub2

I installed Ubuntu about 7 times now trying to set the BIOS up other ways. This BIOS don't see the SATA drive as a 10TB.

All seems to go very good installing till time to reboot and it all ways says no boot device found.

I guess because it's on a 10TB hard drive. Is there some way I can install Ubuntu server on a 10TB hard drive were the BIOS don't support that? Because when installing Ubuntu see it as a 10TB drive.

Hope some one can help been working on this for all most a week now.

-Raymond Day

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain "*This BIOS don't see the SATA drive as a 10TB*." What does the BIOS report that drive to be?

Answer (score 0):

With an old BIOS, it can only read a disk up to some max size.  With disk sizes growing so much over time, this max size is basically limited to the beginning of the disk.  For this reason, a small partition (/boot) at the beginning of the disk will allow the kernels to be seen by the BIOS and to boot. Try adding a /boot of 500-1000MB as the first partition on the disk when you install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by installing it on a 2TB SSD and then the 10TB HDD I just did a symbolic link to it and it's just formatted as ext4 Partition table format: GPT.

It's working very good now. The BIOS can see the 2TB and Ubuntu can see the 10TB but when it was in LVM it just could not boot from it.

But the boot 2TB is in LVM and not going to add any other drive to it.

-Raymond Day